# Limit recalculations on properties

Tags: c#, optimization

I have the following system of properties on my Orbit. I have noticed that the SemiMinor in particular takes a lot to constantly recalculate. _focal1, _focal2 and _tilt CAN change, however, so these properties need to be receptive to such change. Is there any way I can notify these properties of such a change, and recalculate if and only if they are such notified?

Thus far I've tried messing around with setting a boolean if any of the values got changed and then checking for it in the getter (using an inline if to use a stored variable or override it), but that resulted in a major mess with when to unset said boolean (as these properties can be called for in any number and order).

I figure this is a common issue so there has to be a cleaner solution than that.

```
public float Apoapsis {
    get => Mathf.Max(_focal1, _focal2);
}

public float Periapsis {
    get => Mathf.Min(_focal1, _focal2);
}

public float Tilt {
    get => (_tilt + (_focal2 > _focal1 ? 180 : 0)) % 360;
}

public float SemiMinor {
    get => Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(SemiMajor, 2) - Mathf.Pow(SemiMajor - Periapsis, 2));
}

public float SemiMajor {
    get => (Apoapsis + Periapsis) / 2;
}
```

Comment: You can just set the property values when the things they depend on change. If you need to expose the properties as readonly, then use a private `set`.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know anything about Orbit, but a very common way is to use [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?). Actually a very old interface (.NET 2.0 or so), it had a massive surge in uses with WPF. The example code also protects agaisnt excessive raising of events:

```
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }  

    public string CustomerName  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return this.customerNameValue;  
        }  

        set  
        {  
            if (value != this.customerNameValue)  
            {  
                this.customerNameValue = value;  
                NotifyPropertyChanged();  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

I am unsure how well this works with floats, however. Float math is notoriously inprecise so you might still get a unbroken chain of ChangeNotifications, if the results are something like 1.000001 and 1.00002.

Comment: Typically, rather than `==` or `!=`, one would compare `abs(float1-float2) <= Float.Epsilon`.

Comment: This topic, in the general sense, has a lot of nice scenarios where the correct answer is not given, it has to be found. As an example, if you change a property A, and there's a calculated property B that depends on it, do you recalculate that B property immediately, sort of as part of changing A, or do you only flag B as "out of date" so that the next read of B evaluates and caches the result until again being told it's out of date? Then what about properties depending on B? Are they out of date too? How do you communicate this kind of thing? Also, all of this requires careful manual coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make all your properties to explicitly rely on backing field, your `_focal1, _focal2 and _tilt` could potentially have extra calculation logic in `set` method that will update all dependant backing fields as well as whatever field if being set.

This way your calculations will only happen if your properties are being updated.

Comment: Do let me know if this makes sense at all or you'd like a code snippet (that I'll only be able to provide in a few hours though)

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, `SemiMinor` takes a lot to recalculate. This is because of your very inefficient property setup. Let's take a look at what happens when you add a `Console.WriteLine` inside the getter on each of your properties and make a single request for `SemiMinor`:

```
SemiMinor calculated
SemiMajor calculated
Apoapsis calculated
Periapsis calculated
SemiMajor calculated
Apoapsis calculated
Periapsis calculated
Periapsis calculated
```

Instead of doing the computation inside the getter, you should do the computations once when the values change, and set the properties. Each property would simply be defined like:

```
public float Apoapsis { get; set; }
```

Or, if you don't want external code to be able to set the property values:

```
public float Apoapsis { get; private set; }
```

Then when you change the values of `_focal1` or `_focal2` just update the property with `Apoapsis = Mathf.Max(_focal1, _focal2);`

You might simplify your code a bit by making a single method that updates all the values:

```
void updateProperties()
{
  Apoapsis = Mathf.Max(_focal1, _focal2);
  .
  .
  .
}
```